# Handling 1 json split between controllers in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a bit of an interesting problem I am trying to currently figure out using angular.

I have 1 json object I need to use split between 2 controllers, I want to be able to change (save new items and delete json) the json in each controller separately. So when I modify something in one controller it just saves that part of the json - not the whole thing.

I will explain this as clearly as I can -

I have a factory that sends the json to both controllers, here's what it looks like(fake json data for now)

```
.factory("UserService", function($http) {

var LevelsHere = $http.get("/assets/images/generated.json")
          .success(function(data){
            return data;
          });
return {
    all: function() {
      return LevelsHere;
    }
  };

})
```

Each controller then lists it as a dependancy then calls it like so -

```
UserService.all().then(function(data){
            $scope.listTable = data.data;    
        });
```

This works great, and the 2way data binding  is awesome in this case because if i change something in 1 controller, it changes immediately in the other. My real problem with this is I want to be able to save the content changed in the json in each controller individually.

So, the Json has a parent (name) and 2 children. Each controller has access to the parent and 1 of the children so for example. controller 1 has parent and child 1, and controller 2 has parent and child 2. When I want to click my save function - for example in controller 1 I want to save the json to the backend to overwrite the old stuff **but only** from the controller I am choosing to save. So Even if i made changes in controller 2, when I save 1, i Just want it to send parent(it's index) and child 1 to overwrite.

I think the problem may root from the fact that I am fully binding the data in each controller to all the the json maybe? Currently I am just trying to send the $scope.listTable back, and it's registering all the changes (between both sections).

Apologies if I rambled on here - I am trying to be as clear as possible. Thanks for taking the time to read!

**EDIT** I was thinking - and I don't know if this is possible so bear with me - Can it be designated that the json i bring into listTable only binds to what it needs. So for example - controller 1 only binded to all the parent and child 1 (and not child 2). Is this possible?

**EDIT 2** Following up on the previous edit - I think I boiled down the question to - can I only save certain parts of the json instead of the whole object. I cannot have it save both child 1 and 2 at the same time because it might overwrite things that are not meant to be saved at that time. so it's either - can I just use the selected pieces of json, or can I just save the selected pieces of json. thanks again for reading!